# Angular loading component only when they can be visible

Tags: angular

Hello I have a question about lifecycle of components. When can I have this component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
ngOnInit(){
alert("On init!")
}
}
```

And use in parent component:

```
@Component({
    template: '<div *ngIf="isVisible">
     <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onClick()"></button>'
})
export class ParentComponent{
  isVisible: boolean;
  onClick(){
   this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
  }
}
```

When isVisible is false, component is not visible but the ngOnInit method is called.
It is way how to initialize component when can actually be seen?

Comment: what is isVisible? where does it come from?

Comment: It is variable from parent component. maybe can be set by click event

Comment: so where is input ? post the complete code

Comment: I've updated my code even though I think it's not related to my query

Comment: It should not happen. Are you sure you don't have an instance of `<my-component></my-component>` elsewhere in your template that's triggering the alert?

Comment: Ensure that the template is defined with back ticks and not single quotes.